# How to use UNIQUE constrain in android SQLitehelper class?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application user have to enter a unique name i want to add UNIQUE constraint into create 
table statement but it is not working

my create statement is:

```
private static final String sql = "create table "
      + TBL_MASTER + "( " + T_ID
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + T_NAME + " text not null UNIQUE )";
```

inserting statement is

```
private void setdb() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();


    final ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
    vals.put(helper.T_NAME,name);

    System.out.println("String"+name);              
    db.insert(helper.TBL_MASTER, null, vals);
    db.close();
}
```

here name is a String accepting value from a EditText view

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean?

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe there's a problem with the content of T_NAME.

Comment: Check TBL_MASTER, T_ID and T_NAME. I've replaced it's values and the statement works fine.

Comment: does it work without UNIQUE ?

Comment: sorry @MillaresRoo table is there but data is not been inserted

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).